# How to update multiple rows of same column in one query using FoxPro database?

Tags: database, foxpro

I want to update the multiple balance according to their invoice number in just one query. But the code below seems like the FoxPro not accepting it.

**PS: I'm only using Visual FoxPro 6 as a database on my Classic ASP website.**

```
 UPDATE accounts_receivables SET balance = 
      CASE invoice_no 
       WHEN 3 THEN 6
       WHEN 4 THEN 8
       ELSE balance
      END
      WHERE invoice_no IN (3,4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work with VFP6:

```
UPDATE accounts_receivables SET balance = iif(invoice_no=3, 6, iif(invoice_no=4, 8, balance)) WHERE invoice_no IN (3,4)
```

That is also logically the same as writing as:

```
UPDATE accounts_receivables SET balance = iif(invoice_no=3, 6, 8)) WHERE invoice_no IN (3,4)
```

as long as you are only filtering on 3, 4.

However, you could also use do this via VFPOLEDB (even from within VFP6), and then you could as well write as a VFP9 supported query (since you say "ASP" likely you are already accessing the data via a VFP driver instead of direct access, you might simply use VFPOLEDB and utilize VFP9 supported SQL).

Sample in VFP (almost the same code from within ASP or VBA):

```
Local oCon, oCmd
oCon = Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
oCmd = Createobject("ADODB.Command")

oCmd.CommandType = 1
oCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE accounts_receivables"+;
    " SET balance = icase(invoice_no=3, 6, invoice_no=4, 8, balance)"+;
    " WHERE invoice_no IN (3,4)"

oCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=c:\MyDataFolder"
oCon.Open()

oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon
oCmd.Execute
```

And saying ASP, if you really meant ASP.Net at this tiem rather than the old classic ASP, then you could even do that simpler like:

```
string sql = @"UPDATE accounts_receivables
    SET balance = icase(invoice_no=3, 6, invoice_no=4, 8, balance)
    WHERE invoice_no IN (3,4)"; 
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=c:\MyDataFolder"))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql,con))
{
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! But how can I update if the records are more than two? Also I am using Classic ASP

Comment: Maybe the icase doesn't supported by the VFP6, the error says 'File 'icase.prg' does not exist'

Comment: @iJ4419, you can update multiple as I showed in the code above. icase() is NOT supported by VFP6, however, since you are using classic ASP, you can simply use OLEDB (VFPOLEDB) with ADODB as I showed in the code above. VFPOLEDB. supports VFP9 and thus it supports VFP9 compatible SQL as well as iCase().

Comment: And saying multiple, if you have many matches (ie: 2-4, 3-6, 4-X, 5-Y ...) then using iif() or iCase() is not the way to go (as it is not the way to go in SQL server using "case when ... end"). In that case you should have a secondary cursor (likely crafted at runtime) that contains the value pairs for matches. You can then do an update from that cursor using VFPOLEDB (and thus enhanced SQL support that is not available in VFP6).

Comment: I did something and it works for 10 records only. I rely on your code and nested 9 iif. So I update it whenever there's already 10 records and just reset the string. Thank you for your answer man! Really appreciate it :))

Comment: @iJ4419, maybe I was not clear, you CAN use ICASE when you connect via ADODB. For many items, using a secondary cursor is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You must use ICASE() function instead. Like this:

```
 UPDATE accounts_receivables SET balance = 
      ICASE (
       invoice_no = 3, 6,
       invoice_no = 4, 8,
       "balance" 
            )
      WHERE invoice_no IN (3,4)
```

Comment: FoxPro says "Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword"

Comment: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e37'

[Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]File 'icase.prg' does not exist.

Comment: What version of Visual FoxPro are you using? Works in VFP 9.0 SP2

Comment: Test this line only:   ? ICASE(1+1=2,"First is true",1+1=3,"Second is false","None are true")

Comment: I'm using Visual FoxPro 6

Comment: Also, I'm only using VF6 as a database on my ASP website.

Comment: You are using ODBC which doesn't support later than VFP6??? VFP6 doesn't support icase(), VFP9 does (you can and should do via VFPOLEDB, OLEDB drvier as shown in my reply).

Comment: Ohh I think that's why Icase doesn't recognize by the VFP6. Thanks for the info man.